# library for transforming a node tree

Tags: python, refactoring, tree, expression-trees, nodes

I'd like to be able to express a general transformation of one tree into another without writing a bunch of repetitive spaghetti code. Are there any libraries to help with this problem? My target language is Python, but I'll look at other languages as long as it's feasible to port to Python.

Example: I'd like to transform this node tree: (please excuse the [S-expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression))

```
(A (B) (C) (D))
```

Into this one:

```
(C (B) (D))
```

As long as the parent is A and the second ancestor is C, regardless of context (there may be more parents or ancestors). I'd like to express this transformation in a simple, concise, and re-usable way. Of course this example is very specific. Please try to address the general case.

Edit: [RefactoringNG](http://kenai.com/projects/refactoringng/pages/Tutorial) is the kind of thing I'm looking for, although it introduces an entirely new grammar to solve the problem, which i'd like to avoid.  I'm still looking for more and/or better examples.

---

Background:

I'm able to convert python and cheetah (don't ask!) files into tokenized tree representations, and in turn convert those into [lxml](http://lxml.de/) trees. I plan to then re-organize the tree and write-out the results in order to implement automated refactoring. XSLT seems to be the standard tool to rewrite XML, but the syntax is terrible (in my opinion, obviously) and nobody at our shop would understand it.

I could write some functions which simply use the lxml methods (.xpath and such) to implement my refactorings, but I'm worried that I will wind up with a bunch of purpose-built spaghetti code which can't be re-used.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this in Python code. I've used strings for the leaves, but this will work with any objects.

```
def lift_middle_child(in_tree):
    (A, (B,), (C,), (D,)) = in_tree

    return (C, (B,), (D,))

print lift_middle_child(('A', ('B',), ('C',), ('D',))) # could use lists too
```

This sort of tree transformation is generally better performed in a functional style - if you create a bunch of these functions, you can explicitly compose them, or create a composition function to work with them in a point-free style.

Because you've used s-expressions, I assume you're comfortable representing trees as nested lists (or the equivalent - unless I'm mistaken, lxml nodes are iterable in that way). Obviously, this example relies on a known input structure, but your question implies that. You can write more flexible functions, and still compose them, as long as they have this uniform interface.

Here's the code in action: http://ideone.com/02Uv0i

Now, here's a function to reverse children, and using that and the above function, one to lift and reverse:

```
def compose2(a,b): # might want to get this from the functional library
    return lambda *x: a(b(*x))

def compose(*funcs): #compose(a,b,c) = a(b(c(x))) - you might want to reverse that
    return reduce(compose2,funcs)

def reverse_children(in_tree):
    return in_tree[0:1] + in_tree[1:][::-1] # slightly cryptic, but works for anything subscriptable

lift_and_reverse = compose(reverse_children,lift_middle_child) # right most function applied first - if you find this confusing, reverse order in compose function.

print lift_and_reverse(('A', ('B',), ('C',), ('D',)))
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. It seems like these small utility functions could get quite numerous, and hard for an outsider to understand. Is there no standardized collection of functional tools?

Comment: Interesting.  What happens if the input tree doesn't have the right shape?  I think you get a runtime error, and that makes these functions hard to trial-apply.   One can fix that by adding lots of checking logic to each function, but then the simplicity of this idea disappears and it turns back into tree-crawling.

Comment: @bukzor: 1) transformations on code *are* functions in the abstract  2) as a practical matter, to do serious transformation on code, you tend to need a lot of them.  The question about "is there a standardized set" is variously asked by people that want refactoring tools.  The usual answer is "no", the set you need depends on what you want to do, in the same way there is no standardized set of "functions".  That's why it is important to be able to express transformations easily.

Comment: @IraBaxter You'll get an exception of known type. I don't see how this makes things difficult. You certainly wouldn't add elaborate checking, you would use exception handling.

Comment: @bukzor There might be a standardised basis set, but I doubt you'll find a comprehensive implementation. You might like to do some research on that. However, the point of doing this easily is that you can write your own, and the point of composing them is that you can avoid a lot of coding.

Comment: @Marcin: ah, I'm not a Python expert.  I tried a broken match using your example at ideone, and got a program break, leading to the question.  I should have realized that was probably a catchable exception, which makes my objection moot, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want IMHO is an [program transformation system](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html), which allows you to parse and transform code using the patterns expressed in the *surface syntax* of the source code (and even the target language) to express the rewrites directly.

You will find that even if you can get your hands on an XML representation of the Python tree, that the effort to write an XSLT/XPath transformation is more than you expect; trees representing real code are messier than you'd expect, XSLT isn't that convenient a notation, and it cannot express directly common conditions on trees that you'd like to check (e.g., that two subtrees are the same).  An final complication with XML: assume its has been transformed. How do you regenerate the source code syntax from which came?  You need some kind of prettyprinter.

A general problem regardless of how the code is represented is that without information about scopes and types (where you can get it), writing correct transformations is pretty hard.  After all, if you are going to transform python into a language that uses different operators for string concat and arithmetic (unlike Java which uses "+" for both), you need to be able to decide which operator to generate.  So you need type information to decide.  Python is arguably typeless, but in practice most expressions involve variables which have only one type for their entire lifetime.  So you'll also need flow analysis to compute types.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) has all of these capabilities (parsing, flow analysis, pattern matching/rewriting, prettyprinting), and [robust parsers](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds) for many languages including Python.   (While it has flow analysis capability instantiated for C, COBOL, Java, this is not instantiated for Python.  But then, you said you wanted to do the transformation regardless of context).

To express your rewrite in DMS on Python syntax close to your example (which isn't Python?)

```
  domain Python;

  rule revise_arguments(f:IDENTIFIER,A:expression,B:expression,
                                     C:expression,D:expression):primary->primary
  =  " \f(\A,(\B),(\C),(\D)) "
  -> " \f(\C,(\B),(\D)) ";
```

The notation above is the DMS rule-rewriting language (RSL).  The "..." are metaquotes that separate Python syntax (inside those quotes, DMS knows it is Python because of the domain notation declaration) from the DMS RSL language.  The \n inside the meta quote refers to the syntax variable placeholders of the named nonterminal type defined in the rule parameter list.  Yes,  (...) inside the metaquotes are Python ( ) ... they exist in the syntax trees as far as DMS is concerned, because they, like the rest of the language, *are* just syntax.

The above rule looks a bit odd because I'm trying to follow your example as close as possible, and from and expression language point of view, your example is odd precisely because it does have unusual parentheses.

With this rule, DMS could parse Python (using its Python parser) like

```
        foobar(2+3,(x-y),(p),(baz()))
```

build an AST, match the (parsed-to-AST) rule against that AST, rewrite it to another AST corresponding to:

```
        foobar(p,(x-y),(baz()))
```

and then prettyprint the surface syntax (valid) python back out.

If you intended your example to be a transformation on LISP code, you'd
need a LISP grammar for DMS (not hard to build, but we don't have much
call for this), and write corresponding surface syntax:

```
 domain Lisp;

  rule revise_form(A:form,B:form, C:form, D:form):form->form
  =  " (\A,(\B),(\C),(\D)) "
  -> " (\C,(\B),(\D)) ";
```

You can get a better feel for this by looking at [Algebra as a DMS domain](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html).

If your goal is to implement all this in Python... I don't have much help.
DMS is a pretty big system, and it would be a lot of effort to replicate.

Comment: Hi Ira. I think i've seen you hawking this before :) How easy is it for a third party to add a new language front-end? What's your licencing story? I assume it's closed source.

Comment: DMS is designed to enable the addition of new languages, in support of building arbitrary software analysis and transformation tools.  It is also designed to be *used* by 3rd parties; the world is a much bigger place than we can tackle ourselves.  DMS has complete sets of reference manuals and even training classes if you want them.   For commercial details, contact my company; you can find it easily from the site.

Comment: Yes, DMS is closed source, and commercially licensed.  To spare you "surprise", many people consider it expensive. Everybody has an opinion; we think it cheap for what it does, that is needed for practical use.  If you examine the available solutions, you find the supply is pretty thin, because it is hard to do all the things it does.  Clang has some interesting overlap, but doesn't do Python. Python has an AST package, but doesn't handle source-to-source rewrites.  So, you can have free and a non-solution, or you can have the best answer that 15 linear years to several PhDs can package.

Comment: Thanks for the straight talk.

Comment: ... "to several" should be "of several".

Comment: What happens if the input tree doesn't have the right shape? More generally, how do you handle error conditions? I note that your examples don't look any more concise than mine. Presumably there are benefits that appear in other ways.

Comment: For DMS, transformations are explicit objects, and can be handled as singletons or sets.   An Apply operator applies a singleton/set at a point on the AST.  The transformations in the set are attempted conceptually serially (but in a nondeterministic order from the programmer's point of view).  If any one succeeds, it is applied and Apply returns true.  One can apply the set by using a simple while loop.  The reason for the set application is that the test to see which one applies can be made more efficient by combining the sets.  There's a correspondingly efficient pattern match using a set.

Comment: Transformations also have complex matching conditions other than just structure.  You can insist that two subtrees have the same shape, or that subtrees match additional patterns or other arbitrary criteria, some built into the transformation rule language, some by escaping to arbitrary procedural predicates. There's an entire DSL that makes up the rule language, allowing you to write and compose patterns and rules we think conventiently. And this matters when you write hundreds to accomplish a complex task.

Comment: A really significant advantage, we believe, is that these rules are stated in terms of the *surface syntax* of the language you are trying to manipulate, rather than its AST.  [You can refer to AST nodes if you wish, but usually there's no need]. A consequential property: because the patterns are syntax checked against the grammar, you can't write a broken pattern, and transforms that you apply can't (unless you insist) produce ASTs that are not well formed, minimizing debugging.  You can see a small example of all this at http://www.semdesigns.com/products/DMS/SimpleDMSDomainExample.html

Comment: The phrase "combining the sets" 3 comments above should have been "combining the conditions (structural and semantic) of the set members so it only has to test each fragment once".  One other significant advantage of DMS's pattern matching: it can handle associative/commutative operators, which is a nightmare to do with pure structural matches.

Comment: That's really cool. Still, I'd probably rather always avoid programme transformation, for the obvious reason that even with DMS, there's an irreducible level of difficulty. Presumably DMS is also useful for data transformation, which I imagine is a larger market.

Comment: Manipulating programs is a complex activity: you either want to reshape ("refactor") a complex artifact (code for a program) without breaking the implicit semantics it has, or worse, you want to adjust the implicit semantics ("wish my program did something different") in a reliable way.  Much of the problem is induced not by the tools, but by the programming languages themselves: consider the implicit semantics of a C++11 program.  The only thing worse than trying to revise programs with complex tools, is trying to revise them by hand, where you get no gaurantees that any thing useful happens.